# Fire an event after a local delete jqgrid

Tags: events, jqgrid, local

So what I am trying to do is fire an event AFTER a local delete has been done on the jqgrid.  The reason for this is because I am dealing with a global save on the website so I am not posting directly to the server.  I am storing the data in JSON form within a hidden element on the page so when the user finally saves the element value is grabbed and sent to the server along with all the other data.

The issue I am having is that when I delete a row from the jqgrid I am not able to update the hidden element with the change, so if the user saves after that it is like the remove never happened.

```
      $("#translationMappingGrid").jqGrid({
    data: mydata, 
    datatype: "local", 
    mtype: 'GET',
    colNames:['From','To', 'Type'],
    colModel :[ 
        {name:'from',index:'from', width:180, align:"left",sorttype:"float", editable: true, editrules:{custom:true, custom_func:validateIPGridInput}}, 
        {name:'to',index:'to', width:180, align:"left",sorttype:"float", editable: true, editrules:{custom:true, custom_func:validateIPGridInput}}, 
        {name:'type',index:'type', width:200,align:"left",sorttype:"float", editable: true, 
            edittype:"select", formatter:'select', editoptions:{
                value:"0:Never Translate;1:Always Translate;2:Only If Source;3:Only If Destination"}
        }, 
    ],
    pager: '#pager',
    rowNum:10,
    rowList:[10,20,30],
    sortname: 'invid',
    sortorder: 'desc',
    viewrecords: true,
    gridview: true,
    caption: 'Mapping',
    editurl: 'probe.sysinfo.ajax',
    url:'clientArray',
    onSelectRow: function(id){ 
            jQuery('#translationMappingGrid').jqGrid('restoreRow',lastsel2); 
            //below are the parameters for edit row, the function is called after a successful edit has been done
            //jQuery("#grid_id").jqGrid('editRow',rowid, keys, oneditfunc, succesfunc, url, extraparam, aftersavefunc,errorfunc, afterrestorefunc);
            jQuery('#translationMappingGrid').jqGrid('editRow',id,true,"","","","",function () {
                setTranslationMappingJSON(getGridDataJSONString(this));
                window.parent.document.getElementById('notificationDiv').style.display= "";
                }); 

            lastsel2=id; 
    },
    afterInsertRow: function(rowid, rowdata, rowelem ){
        //alert("after insert row");
        setTranslationMappingJSON(getGridDataJSONString(this));
        window.parent.document.getElementById('notificationDiv').style.display= "";
    }


  });

  //adds buttons to jqgrid nav bar
  jQuery("#translationMappingGrid").navGrid('#pager',{
        edit:false,add:true,del:true,search:false,refresh:true
        }, {
            closeAfterAdd:true,
            closeAfterEdit: true
        },
        {
            closeAfterAdd:true,
            closeAfterEdit: true,
            afterSubmit: function(response, postdata) {
                alert("after complete row");
                setTranslationMappingJSON(getGridDataJSONString(this));
                window.parent.document.getElementById('notificationDiv').style.display= "";
                return [true,""];
            }
        });
```

As indicated in the code above I am successfully updating the hidden element with the changes on both add and edit (inline) via afterrestorefunc, but this is not working for delete.

I have tried using afterSubmit in the code above, but this is not working either.  I have been working on this for a few days now and have come to the conclusion that I might have to write my own custom code for the delete button entirely, but I am hoping this is not the case.

Comment: I got excited when I saw you found a solution, unfortunately our cases are a bit different. I quit using navgrid, but still I would like to have some event raised when a row is removed (by 'delRowData', like I'm using, for example). But nice that you found it out by yourself, very good description!

Answer (score 1):

The OP wrote in an edit:

> So it appears as though I was staring at the issue for too long and was missing the obvious....lucky me. I found out two things:
>
> 1. Using afterSubmit was the wrong thing to use, instead I should be using afterComplete.
> 2. I had tried using afterComplete before trying afterSubmit and the reason it was not working it because I am putting them both within the "add" parameters and NOT the delete. Once again, I feel pretty awesome for that one :)
>
> Well now that I have figured that out here is the code snippet that saved my life:
>
> ```
>     jQuery("#translationMappingGrid").navGrid('#pager',{
>     edit:false,add:true,del:true,search:false,refresh:true
>     }, {
>         closeAfterAdd:true,
>         closeAfterEdit: true
>     },
>     {
>         closeAfterAdd:true,
>         closeAfterEdit: true
>     },{
>         afterComplete:
>             function () {
>                 //saves the changed JSON string to the hidden element
>                 setTranslationMappingJSON(getGridDataJSONString(jQuery('#translationMappingGrid')));
>                 window.parent.document.getElementById('notificationDiv').style.display= "";
>             }                       
>     });
> ```
>
> This is tested and the function is called after the delete has been performed and saves the local changes to my hidden element.
>
> For anyone who is curious about what the format is:
>
> ```
>           /* The following is the setup 
>         navGrid(<name>, {<buttons, true/false},
>         {
>         <edit parameters>
>         },
>         {
>         <add parameters>
>         },
>         {
>         <delete parameters>
>         }  
>       */
> ```
>
> Thanks for everyone who might have started working on this, and definitely thanks to the developers of jqgrid. Best javascript grid I have ever worked with!

Comment: ([Question answered in an edit and converted to a community wiki](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/267434/what-is-the-appropriate-action-when-the-answer-to-a-question-is-added-to-the-que)).

Comment: Note: this works only for FORM delete (the navgrid object) not for inline delete